# Can't work out why each span overlaps during animation

Tags: html, css

Basically just trying to make an animation which switches between an 0 and an o repeatedly without them overlaping.

Any ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/ckfoch7v/

```
.rw-words-1 span{
animation: rotateWordsFirst 0.3s linear 0s infinite;
left: 11px;
top: 2px;
}


.rw-words span:nth-child(2) { 
    animation-delay: 0.2s; 

}
.rw-words span:nth-child(3) { 
    animation-delay: 0.4s; 

}

.rw-words span:nth-child(4) { 
    animation-delay: 0.6s; 

}
.rw-words span:nth-child(5) { 
    animation-delay: 0.8s; 

}

.rw-words span:nth-child(6) { 
    animation-delay: 0.9s; 

}


@keyframes rotateWordsFirst {
    0% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: linear; height: 0px; }
    95% { opacity: 1;}
    98% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

Comment: You have multiple elements and the reason for overlap is that the at 0.3s mark, the first child is starting its second iteration whereas the second child is in the middle of its first iteration and so on. You need to modify the keyframe settings accordingly to avoid such an overlap. Have a look at the method mentioned in my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32396638/css3-fading-in-and-out-delay/32397116#32397116

Answer (score 1):

Try with two spans.

It will work.

**HTML**

```
   <div class="alien">  <span>\ /</span>
    <span>.</span>

        <section class="rw-wrapper">
            <div class="rw-sentence">
                <div class="rw-words rw-words-1">   
                  <span>0</span>
                  <span>o</span>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

**[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ckfoch7v/1/)**

Comment: Say i wanted to cycle through words/sentences letter by letter though? IE. 'h-e-l-l-o'

Comment: +1 Also the first delay should be 1/2 of the duration and the second delay should be equal to the duration. If duration is 0.8, One is 0.4 and  Two is 0.8. > https://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/ckfoch7v/2/

Comment: @miro: Your comment would work with a slight modification of the keyframes but not the answer provided here. It wouldn't solve the overlapping issue. I have linked my answer to a similar question in the comments to the question.