# Making each <li> animate later than the previous one

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

Say if i have an un ordered list of red background blocks.

I want the animation to target each li and have a stretching type affect.

how can i make each list animate with different speeds? The animation should have a delay going over each li.

example:

first li stretches, then the second li stretches, so on and so on.

```css
li {
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: stretch 2`enter code here`s;
}

@keyframes stretch {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can manually set a custom delay for each element in CSS using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay but a JavaScript or preprocessed CSS approach will be far more maintainable. @Raman has a decent answer using jQuery. Hopefully someone else will post an answer using SASS loops or a PostCSS plugin.

Comment: Are the no. of elements static or dynamic? If it is static then you don't need JS or pre-processors. Just use the logic provided [**in this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32396638/delay-in-infinite-fade-in-out-css3-animation/32397116#32397116) (for infinite loops) or [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33568319/expand-circles-sequentially-using-css/33568849#33568849) (for finite loops). If it is dynamic then you would have to use JS. Pre-processors wouldn't help for that case because the pre-processor would not know how many elements are there in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need some JavaScript to do this. Please follow [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ramanbedi1989/ejr9fueh/) link and see if it works.Here is the jQuery snippet that I have written:

```
$(function(){
    var delay = 0;
    $('ul>li').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css('animation', 'stretch 2s');
        $this.css('animation-delay', delay+'s');
        $this.on("webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend oAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend", function(){
            $this.width('100%');
        });
        delay += 2;
    });
});
```

Comment: @Richard Bustos, can you please mark the answer as accepted if it was able to solve your problem.

Comment: This is a great input! not quite what im looking for. Each animation doesnt have to finish before the other. Just needs to have some delay one after the other. Some what like a wave. I am also looking for just a css solution